# Default Apache config is not matching unmatched requests

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

### Environment

Ubuntu 16.04 / Apache 2.4.18

### Problem

One of my Apache configs is matching **every** request, regardless of whether the ServerName matches. Even different domains are matching, not just subdomains. How do I determine a fix for why this one config is matching everything?

### Details

I have two active configurations, `000-default` and a config for one of my domains.

Problem is, if I enable the config for that one domain, that config handles **all** requests, no matter if I'm using a fake subdomain, or even *a completely different domain* that is set up to point to that server's IP.

To be clear, I don't yet have a config for that other domain, so it shouldn't be matching anything.

Configs appear to be loaded in the proper order, so the 000-default should be the default config for nonmatching requests.

### Configuration

```
# 000-default.conf
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName default
  ServerSignature Off
  Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

.

```
# example-com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ServerSignature Off

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Since my other domain doesn't match that first `RewriteCond`, it just returns a blank 200. So probably no need to pay attention to the fact that nothing is serving that HTTPS route:

```
# curl -I http://example.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found <== This is good, that redirects as expected
$ curl -I http://fake.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK <== That's bad, it hit the example.com config, failed the RewriteCond, and just returned a blank 200
$ curl -I http://other-domain.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK <== Also bad, same reason as above
```

Apache seems to be loading stuff in the right order:

```
# apache2ctl -S
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1
VirtualHost configuration:
*:*                    default (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:3)
*:80                   example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example-com.conf:1)
```

With this load order, `000-default` **should** be handling nonmatching sites, but it's not. Can anyone see the deal with my config that's causing this?

Comment: Don't know if this will fix anything but three suggestions about 000-default... First, the 2.4.x line of Apache does not require the NameVirtualHost directive (and it is in fact deprecated). Second, I would replace <VirtualHost *> with <VirtualHost *:80>. Most configurations I see have this syntax even for 000-default. Third, you may want to disable (a2dissite) and re-enable (a2ensite) 000-default regardless to make sure it's is actually enabled (don't forget to restart Apache obviously).

Comment: Well, what you said is exactly what fixed it. Probably specifying that port. I admit my Apache-fu is weak, so I thank you greatly for your assistance.

Comment: Yeah my suspicion is the port as well. In any case, you're welcome. Glad it's fixed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at three things in regards to the 000-default configuration file:

- The 2.4.x line of Apache does not require the NameVirtualHost directive (and it is in fact deprecated), so I would remove this.
- I would replace `<VirtualHost *>` with `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Most configurations I see have this syntax even for 000-default. Not having this format could interfere with the host being used for requests.
- You should disable (a2dissite) and re-enable (a2ensite) the 000-default configuration file to make sure it's is actually enabled (don't forget to restart Apache as well).